# Model converted to Script - No editing mode?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model that an ESRI associate sent me as an example. When I run the model everything is great. I click on the model and because the seleting features is a parameter, it automatically starts an edit session for me to digitize the selecting features. However when I convert this model to a script and try to run as a script, when I run it, the selecting feature parameter is not in edit mode, a polygon does not pop up in the table of contents as a feature class to be digitized like it was with the model. Is there a way to change the model so that the selecting features can be digitized ? Thanks

The first picture shows the model, the second shows the model when I run it, and the third shows the scrip when I run it.[image: figure1][image: figure2][image: figure3]

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# toolbox_scrip3t.py
# Created on: 2013-09-30 13:13:52.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: toolbox_scrip3t <Selecting_Features> <value> 
# Description: 
# test
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Selecting_Features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Selecting_Features == '#' or not Selecting_Features:
    Selecting_Features = "in_memory\\{44DC94EF-CABC-4233-A4AF-CEFD34618B2E}" # provide a default value if unspecified

value = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Local variables:
Input_Points = "FirePerimeter"
Final_Output = value
Selected_Features = Selecting_Features
Input_Points_Layer = "SamplePoints_Layer"

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Input_Points, Input_Points_Layer, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SymbologyField SymbologyField VISIBLE NONE;DomainField DomainField VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;Subtype Subtype VISIBLE NONE;EditField EditField VISIBLE NONE")

# Process: Select Layer By Location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Input_Points_Layer, "INTERSECT", Selecting_Features, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Selected_Features, "EditField", "'%value%'", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Comment: Could you provide additional details as to what you want to do? It's a little unclear... if it does what you want in model builder why are you trying to export as a script?

The script you posted isn't referencing any selection...so that would be my starting point.

Comment: If the model already worked, why did you export to script? I'm a little confused at the entire premise of this question.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. You don't have your shapefile/input referenced at all. For instance you have "Input Points = "Fireperimeter" but that should reference a file like "C:\Shapes\Fireperimeter.shp"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to your question ...

> Is there a way to change the model so that the selecting features can
>   be digitized?

I recommend that you investigate using a **[Feature Set in ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000004t000000)**.

I think exporting your model to a Python script is just an attempt to develop an unnecessary workaround - but be sure to let us know if that is my misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you are right PolyGeo, I did that and it worked. Thanks!!!